# Ignore subproject's history with git-subtree

Tags: git, git-subtree

I want to import a new "module" library into my project using subtree, but when I imported using these commands:

```
git remote add module git@111.111.11.1:serverUrl/module.git
git subtree add --prefix=libraries/module/ module master
```

it brings into git commit history all the history of the "module".

How to ignore "module" history from my project history when adding subtree?

Answer (score 1):

To omit history when adding subtree module please use `--squash` option.

Comment: Thank you but I switched to submodule since it does what I need and better supported by IntelligIdea than subtree.